# Security to the party[Part 39]

Tags: cipher, password

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing — his famous recipe for Spaghetti!
The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.
Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The guard says 5. The guest replies 20

The second guest arrives. The guard says 3 and the guest replies 25

The third guest arrives. The guard says 10 and the guest replies 15.

Your friend walks up. The guard says 4 and you friend replies 15.
He is admitted in.

You now walk up. The guard says 6.

What should you reply.

> guard : 0  guest :20  guard : 1 guest : 15

**Hint 1**

> look at tags closely

Comment: And @North, I'd guess it's part 39 because there seem to be 38 other puzzles using the same format - a bunch of them show up the "related" section of the right sidebar, at least for me

Comment: Are you sure that when they say "four" the person says 15 and not 20? @MackybenJonah

Comment: @North Search for "Security to the Party", you'll see this is apparently the latest resuscitation of a long line of similar, often poorly received puzzles. The spaghetti theme is an ancient P.SE meme of sorts which fortunately died some time ago.

Comment: You should really consider making an account, so you can track your badges and reputation. I think this is the third time I've seen you post here, and each time has been with a different unregistered account.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be

> It depends on the number of letters in the number and that multiplied by 5.

But,

> "Four" times 5 is not 15 unless it is "for" times 5? But this fits with all of the other questions the guard asked.

Still,

> You should say 15 because "six" has three letters.

Comment: Dtz xmtzqi xfd "ybjsyd" gjktwj ymj lzfwi xnhx ymj mtzsix ts dtz.